# How to short a sql case query that uses between

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Hi have this sql query:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN money BETWEEN 0 and 1000 THEN '1000'
   WHEN money BETWEEN 1000 and 2000 THEN '2000'
   WHEN money BETWEEN 2000 and 3000 THEN '3000'
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   WHEN money BETWEEN 19000 and 20000 THEN '20000'

from bank;
```

How can I short this query so I don't use a lot of case statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using  mod subtracting the remainder t from you value by division for 1000

```
SELECT money - MOD( money , 1000 )
FROM bank;
```

or as suggested by @DM you can also use

```
FLOOR((money + 999) / 1000) * 1000
```

the difference should be the same  ..  both involve function  .. but there are nit where condition so this is not in contrast with  indexing

Comment: Alternatively, `FLOOR((money + 999) / 1000) * 1000`. I'm not sure of the performance difference.

Comment: @DM .. I have  update the answer  with  some  my opinion for performance

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the expression:

```
ceiling(money / 1000)
```

The only caveat is that `0` goes into its own group.  To me, that seems like a feature.  But if you don't agree, you could use a `case` expression or arcane arithmetic:

```
ceiling((money - (money = 0)) / 1000)
```